# Absurd issue with Resolution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am encountering an extremely absurd phenomenon. When I run my code on my smartphone **via Unity Remote** or even on the computer, it works as expected. But when I install the APK on the device and run it, the parameters change! Does this have something to do with resolution?

Comment: Is `button` a 3D gameobject or UI element?

Comment: @Kroltan `button` is a UI element

Comment: @JoeBlow Done. Question edited.

Comment: @JoeBlow Did you figure it out? I still didn't...

Comment: hang on - wouldn't you have to convert each of them to a world position? I'm sorry, I find "position of UI items" very confusing myself - not much help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you may need to investigate `ScreenToWorldPoint`,

as in say

```
 pWorldSpace = someCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint( Input.mousePosition );
```

it is a large difficult topic, and I don't know specifically what you need: every project needs custom code for this.  Suggest google for code samples using it